# How to get "forward" controller plugin in service manager in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

According to this https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/plugins/#forward-plugin :

```
$foo = $this->forward()->dispatch('foo', ['action' => 'process']);
return [
    'somekey' => $somevalue,
    'foo'     => $foo,
];
```

I want to get such `$foo` but within the service manager, for example `\MyModule\Service\NewsManager`. How to do this?

Comment: I don't think the `ServiceManager` knows about the `ControllerManager`. But `Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Forward::dispatch()` needs the `Controller` object. Somehow you would have to inject it into your class to be able to use `Plugin` classes.

Comment: @AlainPomirol, it can be done with this `->serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('forward')->dispatch(` in service factory.

Comment: Wow! Great. Thank you